# gnutls_handshake() failure only via jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have to interact with a GIT repository (bitbucket).
If I try any clone/push/pull command via the bash it works fine.

Anyway, if I try to set my clone uri in jenkins I get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins is using GnuTLS to handle the TLS portion of the communication with Bitbucket (that is, the "S" in "HTTPS"). In this case, something is keeping GnuTLS from establishing the TLS session appropriately. There isn't really enough information here to say what that something is, but there are a couple things you could try:

1. Update GnuTLS and/or cURL to a newer version
2. Use a cURL client compiled against OpenSSL
3. Use SSH

Comment: Solved! It was the proxy, now it's ok :)